# Errors while importing Titanium Studio Project

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

am importing a project, The project gets imported successfully. When I am trying to build I get this error

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp normal i386
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

How to solve this? Also the clean button gets disabled

**EDIT**
I have changed the project now, I have imported another project in my workspace, but I am getting a red cross mark on the folder of the project(just like the error which we get in Eclipse in case of Android dev when the build files are missing), however rest all files seem to have no error.

Comment: Restarted the system and Titanium Studio several times...

Comment: go to app directory delete build folder then clean you project and run again ..

Comment: question has been modified

Comment: Dont import the project, instead create another project, then copy / paste from your old projects resources directory into the new one. Then try and build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created another project, pasted the old project's resources into it & the code is being built